# Как отфильтровать многоуровневый массив по ключу и значению?

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно получить `$step = 5`, сейчас делаю это через циклы, проблема в том что очень много записей, хотелось бы в одну строку все записать и чтобы портативно было

Есть разные функции `array_filter, array_map` только не пойму как их использовать чтобы найти вхожнение

```
$value = [
  'status' => [
    'msg' = 'ok',
  ],
  'filters' => [
    'filter_type' => 'price',
    'step' => 5,
  ],
];

$step = false;

if (isset($value['filters']) and is_array($value['filters'])) {
  foreach ($value['filters'] as $filter) {
    if ($filter['filter_type'] === 'price') {
      $step = $filter['step'];
    }
  }
}

// $step = array_filter($value)...
```

Comment: "*проблема в том что очень много записей, хотелось бы в одну строку все записать*"  ---- это как сказать "ножа порезать нет, но хотелось бы чай выпить"

Comment: Для многоуровневых можно использовать рекурсивную функцию